# Можно ли визуально создать GUI для приложения JavaFX в NetBeans

Tags: javafx, netbeans

Недавно начал программировать на JavaFX и самой удобной средой для этого посчитал NetBeans, но не могу разобраться, как визуально создать интерфейс. Перелопатив мануалы, я понял, что это можно сделать как с помощью Swing, так и FXML. Основное требование - чтобы получившееся приложение быстро и без дополнительных требований работало прямо на web-странице.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html
Получишь файл fxml. Тогда метод start будет таким:

```
private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "MainWindow.fxml";

@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            loader.setLocation(MainWindow.class.getResource(RESOURCE_PATH));

            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)loader.load(); // Самый первый вставленый контейнер в fxml файле

            // Show the scene containing the root layout
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
    }
```

Пример есть здесь http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part1/

Comment: Самое приятное, что этот инструмент  поддердивается Intellij Idea и Eclipse...  при изменении FXML файла  JavaFX Scene Builder  можно настроить на автоматическое открытие из этих IDE